# Postgres list databases permission

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a database with a role, that can connect to and **view** that database only.

How I went about it:

```
_, err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE " + database.Name + " ENCODING 'utf8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8'")
_, err = db.Exec("CREATE ROLE " + database.User + " WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '" + database.Password + "'")
_, err = db.Exec("REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE " + database.Name + " FROM PUBLIC")
_, err = db.Exec("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE " + database.Name + " TO " + database.User)
```

The problem is that my role can connect to postgres via:

```
psql -U haruki -W -h localhost
```

Which is okay, but it can list all databases with its corresponding permissions, even though it cannot connect to them.

Is there any way I can **prevent the user from listing all databases**? Or perhaps allow logging in only with the -d flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way restricting this in pgsql.
The `pg_catalog` holds the names of the databases.

Either you have to add a custom layer to do this in between in any language you use or you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917484/allow-postgres-user-to-only-list-his-own-database) by editing the postgresql config and using DDL statements.